# Non linear programming example c, java?

Tags: java, c, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

Do you know a good example of nonlinear programming?, I have search over google, but any text just formulate and do not solve the problem, They mention lingo and even excel for solving it.

Could you please post an example and explain a little of if?

Thanks in advance

P.d
You know the idea is to see some results, and numbers, using C, java.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these (java):

[Example1](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v30/api/com/imsl/math/MinConNLPEx1.html)

[Example2](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v30/api/com/imsl/math/MinConNLPEx2.html)

[Example3](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v30/api/com/imsl/math/MinConNLPEx3.html)

Comment: None of the link is working. Could you please put the code here